# react-i18next navigates back to first screen in navigation on changeLanguage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next, react-i18next

My problem is that when changing language with react-18next it navigates back to first screen.

I call it like this for example:

`i18n.changeLanguage('en')`

and I have init like:

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: en
    },
    nl: {
      translation: nl
    }
  }
})
```

And if my navigation has routes like ['Main', 'Settings', 'Language'] and my language change button is in Language view (I navigate there like: Main -> Settings -> Language), it redirects user to Main screen after language has changed.

Language changes correctly and everything works, apart that it seems to reset everything. I don't have any specific navigation setup.

Anybody has experienced anything like this?

Answer (score 5):

thank you for your question & answer, it helped me resolve this case.
Look, actually you **can** use the useTranslation hook inside the navigation component, but do not pass the t('translation') at the route name.
What you have to do is:

```
 <Tab.Screen
    name="Home" {/* this stays un-translated*/}
    options={{tabBarLabel: t('navigate:home')}} {/* this takes the translation function instead*/}
    component={HomeScreen}
  />
```

source: [This amazing example](https://github.com/amandeepmittal/react-native-examples/blob/a8c1fc0a393d2af628ad36c512af0091bc6bad6d/rnMultiLanguageExample/src/navigation/RootNavigator.js#L35)

Comment: according to the latest documentation, this property is now called `title` instead of `tabBarLabel` --> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#options

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem - I was using useTranslation hook inside my navigation component. So as translations changed there, it also reset navigation to first screen.